# Embedding of flat surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, polyhedra

Let $S$ be a orientable compact surface with a flat euclidean structure with conical singularities (cf. [T] for instance). Let also $\mathcal P$ be a polyhedral euclidean decomposition of $S$ (with vertices at the singular points of the euclidean structure of $S$).

**Question 1**:  can $S$ be realized (as a polyhedral surface) in an euclidean space? If yes, what is known about the set of such `euclidean polyhedral realizations'?

**Question 2**: same questions than above, but for $\mathcal P$ (i.e. an euclidean polyhedral decomposition of $S$ is fixed).

--

Remarks:

- there is no assumption  on the genus of $S$ (when $S$ has genus 0, an answer to the (first part of)  Question 1 is  given by Alexandrov theorem)
- A similar question (but for Riemann surfaces) already appears in [B] (page 9). I guess that a lot has been done on this problem since. Any relevant reference would constitute an interesting answer.

Thanks for any help!

---

[B] Bers L., Riemann surfaces (1958)

[T] Troyanov M. -- *Les surfaces a singularités coniques*. Enseign. Math. **32** (1986), 79–94.

Comment: For genus 0, this is discussed in the monograph of Jürgen Richter-Gebert "Realization spaces of polytopes."  It is published by Springer. There are still PDF copies archived on citeseer and other sites that you can find with google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be that this theorem of Burago & Zalgaller (partially) answers your question?

> **Theorem** (Burago-Zalgaller 1.7). 
>   Every polyhedron $M$ admits an isometric piecewise-linear $C^0$
>   immersion into $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>   If $M$ is orientable or has a nonempty
>   boundary, then $M$ admits an isometric piecewise-linear $C^0$
>   embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

This is from:

- Yu. D. Burago and V. A. Zalgaller. 
  "Isometric piecewise linear immersions of two-dimensional manifolds with polyhedral metrics into $\mathbb{R}^3$.
  *St. Petersburg Math. J.*, 7(3):369--385, 1996. Translated by S. G. Ivanov.
  English translation: 
  [Scanned PDF (15MB)](http://multires.caltech.edu/pubs/BZ96.pdf).

Here is their definition of a "polyhedron":

> By a two-dimensional manifold with polyhedral metric (in brief,
>   a *polyhedron*), we mean a metric space endowed with the structure
>   of a connected compact two-dimensional manifold (possibly with
>   boundary) every point $x$ of which has a neighborhood isometric to
>   the vertex of a cone. ... The metric is locally 
>   flat everywhere except
>   for a finite collection of points; these points are the `true' vertices."

A nice phrase they use in Lemma 2.2 to describe the mapping is that each
triangle becomes a *pleated surface* in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Burango-Zalgallar theorem is quite impressive and is certainly the best answer that can be expected to the first part of Question 1.

Comment: It is an amazing theorem! I believe they do not attempt to bound the number of flat, noncreased triangles in the final construction, but it would be astronomical in most cases.

Comment: Dear Joseph - Do you have a copy of the English translation?  I've not been able to find it online? Thank you!

Comment: @SamNead: Added a link to a scanned PDF.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!