# Softwares to draw euclidean polyhedral surfaces

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, mathematical-software

Let $S$ be an abstract euclidean polyhedral surface. By this, I mean a orientable compact 2D topological surface obtained by gluing together some (convex) euclidean polygons (arbitrary genus).

**Question**: are there softwares to draw $S$ in the 3D euclidean space $\mathbb E^3$?

Formulated this way, my question is certainly too vague. 
What I mean by *drawing $S$ in $\mathbb E^3$* is not determined. A PL isometric immersion $S\rightarrow \mathbb E^3$ would be great.  But anything else leading to nice pictures would be appreciated too...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142284/embedding-of-flat-surfaces/142286

Comment: More specifically: I don't have access to the paper (the english translation is not online) but perhaps unraveling the proof of the theorem by Burago and Zalgaller described in the question I linked to above will help, as that result apparently yields an isometric immersion for arbitrary genus polyhedral surfaces.

Comment: The proof of B&Z is quite far from algorithmic. When I studied it I could not see an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

In 2007 I wrote a "[news-like article](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/Papers/49.pdf)" on

> "The new algorithm of Bobenko and Izmestiev for reconstructing the unique polyhedron determined by given gluings of polygons is described."

I think this partially answers your question...?

[image: ScreenSnapshot]

Comment: Very nice! But it concerns only the genus 0 case...

Comment: The link in your article is now dead but the java program is linked here http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/ps/software.shtml

Comment: @Elbabak: That's correct. [Alexandrov's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlexandrovsTheorem.html) only applies to the genus zero case, and it is Alexandrov's theorem that underlies that algorithm. I do not believe there is anything comparable for arbitrary genus.